# How Do I Update a Live Server Correctly Using Mercurial?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, ftp

I'm new to Mercurial and version control, and although I'm only working on personal PHP application projects (until I hopefully get a job soon) I'm well overdue learning how it all works.

I've been reading about Mercurial all day, but I'm still confused on a few elements...

Firstly, I understand Mercurial CAN push my files straight to my live server, but I don't see many tutorials or examples explaining how this is done, so it leads me to think it's not used often? I currently use FTP to upload my files, and it's error prone to know which files have been modified, so I'd like to eliminate this obviously.

I also see services like BitBucket being mentioned a lot, but if I'm pushing to BitBucket how do I then get my files to my live server? Can I get only the changed files to upload via FTP, or do I need to install Mercurial on my server too or something?

Apologies if this is a basic question, I'm just a little lost as to how companies would/should use this service, and how files and uploads are handled elegantly. How should i go about version control on a personal project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do that, but I'll try to narrow it down to the basic steps involved in a scenario using BitBucket:

1) Install Mercurial on both your dev machine and your live server.

2) Create a repository in BitBucket.

3) Clone the repository to your dev machine using the URL that appears in BitBucket, e.g.:

```
hg clone https://your_user@bitbucket.org/your_account/your_repos .
```

4) Clone the repository to your live server in the same way.

5) Do your dev and commit your code to the local repository on your dev machine (using `hg commit`). Then push the changesets to BitBucket using `hg push`.

6) Once you're ready to deploy the changes to your live server, log in to your live server and run `hg pull -u`.

Comment: So what's the advantage of being on BitBucket? Is it so there's a backup of the repository or so there's somewhere safe for other users to pull(?) files from to work on, or both?

Comment: I would say both. It also sets up the https access for you and has many nice features to manage your repositories, handle pull requests, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I just **use rsync to upload everything**. If you're working by yourself, it's simple and works fine.

I set up an SSL certificate, and then made **a bash shortcut** ,p (target directory):

```
,p() { rsync -avz --delete ./ "user@server.com:/var/www/html/$@/"; }
```

Then, on my local host I can type **,p images** and the current directory will be uploaded to mysite/images.

If you're always uploading to the same place, you can make **a shortcut with no argument**:

```
alias ,pm="rsync -avz --delete ./ "user@server.com:/var/www/html/";
```

Finally, if you just want to **type the command**:

```
rsync -avz --delete ./ "user@server.com:/var/www/html/
```